# Правильная архитектура андроид-приложения

Tags: java, android

Мой начальник, лезет в андроид проект со своим уставом, и это дико бесит. Наш проект превращается в непонятно что. После фразы "это не по java" он начинает переделывать все придумывать непонятные вещи.
Например теперь проект состоит из модулей. `Главный модуль`, `connector`, `core`, `storage`, `models`. Оправдывает возможностью переноса модулей(у нас 2 проекта). Теперь он хочет запускать оба проекта в одном окне студии, для чего подключил второй проект в первый как модуль, сказав что мы избавились от дубликации кода, но оставил модули. А проекты предлагает запускать через лаунчер. Помимо этого, Мы делаем абстракнтые активити, наследуя от них интерфейс, чтобы использовать 1 xml вместо 2х и в потомке из кода меняем внешний вид интерфейса. переменные типа `tvName`  поменял на `nameField`.

Есть ли какие-нибудь доки или гайдлайны, какая-то информация, как правильно создавать архитектуру проекта? Ресурсам startandroid, stackoverflow, примерам официальным с гугла по некоторым вещам не верит. Пусть не смогу переубедить, но сам буду знать как делать правильно. Поделитесь ссылками плиз

Comment: Вопрос не по теме. А откуда вы взяли схему с "tvName"? Очень часто вижу её использование, не только у новичков, но не понимаю, откуда и почему она идет в android

Comment: А вообще, объясните, что это не по java, но в android большое количество абстракций сильно влияет на производительность. Причем влияет заметно и это критично. Вот более-менее приличный ответ http://stackoverflow.com/a/28897967/2971719

Comment: tvName - TextViewName

Comment: Я понимаю, но когда я это вижу, у меня тоже возникает стойкое желание это переименовать. Инфу о типе я могу посмотреть в любой момент, большую часть времени она мне не нужна, часто она не совпадает с реальным положением дел. Часто я там указываю минимально необходимый мне тип, например, могу указать View для ProgressBar или View/TextView для EditText или EditText для собственного класса - переопределенного мной EditText

Comment: ну круто))) за ссылку спасибо. если есть еще материал поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: Похоже на то, что ваш начальник - единственный адекватный разработчик в вашей конторе.

Comment: а подробней? про адекватность

Answer (score 2):

Вещи про модули, избавление от дупликации кода и переименование переменных из `tvName` в `nameField` (избавление от остатков венгерской нотации) звучат абсолютно логично. Про лаунчер и абстрактные активити не совсем понятно что имелось в виду.

По поводу структуры проекта - советую глянуть приложение для конференций Google IO - https://github.com/google/iosched

Это пример от Google который содержится в актуально состоянии, и содержит массу интересных вещей которым стоит поучиться.